# How to exclude certain sections of a site from Mod ReWrite Rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am moving most pages from a site and I want to redirect all requests to a 404 error page except all/any pages in a certain cname on the site, all/any pages in a certain sub-directory on the site and a certain page in a certain directory on the site.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blogs.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/private [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/special-form.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/special-form_submitted.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error404.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/error404.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How is this not working for you?

Comment: i was getting an endless redirect loop in my browser

Comment: and live pages were being rendered rather than being redirected

Comment: You'd also need to exclude your `error404.php` page, since that'll be a client side redirect. you'd redirect to error404, client requests error404, and since it's NOT excluded, you'd trigger ANOTHER redirect to the same page.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks @MarcB. I didn't catch that. I'll give it a try

Comment: the live pages are still rendering

Comment: you're using 301 redirect, make it 302 and clear you cache, once you confirm its working then you change it to 302 otherwise your browser will give you an early version of the redirect due to the type of redirect being used, better yet is if you test your last change with a different browser you haven't used which will not be cached so you can clearly see the changes if any.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Prix. But using 302 did not work. All pages still render to their original location. They do not go to the error page.

Comment: @H.Ferrence did you use a different browser to avoid the previous cache from your 301? Also are you placing the rule inside the `VirtualHost` or inside an `.htaccess`? if the later you need to remove the `/` at the begin of your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Yes @Prix...I used Opera browser (latest/stable). I never use Opera except for testing...I have never render my site in Opera, at leats not in the last 9 months. And "yes", I am using a .htaccess file

Comment: Ok, I am getting closer @Prix. `!^blogs.example.com` worked. `!^/private/` works but only if I remove the trailing "/" which I will updated my question with once I get this fully tested. `!^/public/special-form.php` works but only the page content. The css styling is gone. So that leads me to ask...do I need to pour through my form page and add all included web docs in the .htaccess rewritecond? Things like the .js files, the .css file and php include()'s ?

Comment: @H.Ferrence that depends on your structure you might yes, but you can fit it all in a single condition. Since I don't know your structure I can't tell you how to go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is mainly the `/` at the start of your `RewriteRule`, why?

Because you're using it with an `.htaccess` so the `RewriteRule` path starts without the `/` at the begin.

If it was inside the `VirtualHost` then that would have worked just fine.

---

Basically this is what your rule is telling the server to do after our comments conversation and your update:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# if domain is not blogs.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blogs.example.com [NC]
# and if address does not start with /private 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/private [NC]
# and if the file is not /public/special-form.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/special-form.php [NC]
# and if the file is not /public/special-form_submitted.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/special-form_submitted.php [NC]
# and if the file is not /error404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error404.php [NC]
# then redirect to http://example.com/error404.php
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/error404.php [R=301,L]
```

---

So anything else including images or css or not listed on the conditions would be redirected, in order to avoid that you would have to verify all the needed files within those 2 php pages and white list it, for example with a condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/[^.]+\.(css|pdf|jpg|doc)$ [NC]
```

Basically the above means anything within the public folder that ends with `.css` or `.pdf` or `.doc` or `.jpg` should be displayed.

***NOTE: Keep in mind that if your images and documents and whatever else you need to show to your users from those 2 PHP pages are not within the public folder the above will not work, that was merely an example to illustrate an easy way to couple multiple types of files into it.***

---

You could also resume this 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/special-form.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/special-form_submitted.php [NC]
```

as follow:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(special-form_submitted|special-form)\.php [NC]
```

---

You would end with:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blogs.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/private [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(special-form_submitted|special-form)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/[^.]+\.(css|pdf|jpg|doc)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error404.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/error404.php [R=301,L]
```

---

Just a side information, since you're redirecting anything that does not match the conditions and you're not passing along anything to the redirect, you don't need the `(.*)`, merely using `^` alone will do the job.

Comment: Excellent @Prix. I got it working thanks to your help. Greatly appreciated!